# Retrieving functions specific variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, appcelerator

I'm pretty much a complete noob when it comes to JS and I'm having the hardest time with this.

I'm working with Titanium Appcelerator and I need to use the lon/lat variables outside of the function below, however, when I call them--they show up as undefined. How can I retrieve those variables outside of the function? Any help is a appreciated!

```
function getLocation() {
    current.text = "Finding you...";
    actInd.show();
    currentWindow.setLeftNavButton(actInd);
    Titanium.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e)
    {   

        if (e.error)
        {
            alert('Can not get your current location');
            return;
        }   
            Ti.API.info("Got Location");
            var lon = e.coords.longitude;
            lat = e.coords.latitude;
            altitude = e.coords.altitude;
            current.text = lat+" / "+lon;

    });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the way you're thinking about this.  JavaScript has a bit of a [functional programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) feel to it, and you need to treat it as such.  Especially when dealing with asynchronous operations, such as geolocation.  In short, this is *not* just a scope issue, but an order-of-execution issue as well.

The basic approach here is to provide a function to `getLocation()` that it will, in turn, execute at the proper step.

```
function getLocation( onSuccessCallback ) {
    current.text = "Finding you...";
    actInd.show();
    currentWindow.setLeftNavButton(actInd);
    Titanium.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e)
    {   

        if (e.error)
        {
            alert('Can not get your current location');
            return;
        }   
            Ti.API.info("Got Location");
            var lon = e.coords.longitude;
            lat = e.coords.latitude;
            altitude = e.coords.altitude;
            current.text = lat+" / "+lon;

            if ( 'function' == typeof onSuccessCallback )
            {
              onSuccessCallback( lat, lon );
            }

    });
};
```

And then, where you call `getLocation()`

```
getLocation( function( lat, lon )
{
  Ti.API.info( 'Lat: ' + lat );
  Ti.API.info( 'Lon: ' + lon );
});
```

So to recap: start thinking about how your code executes in the proper order of operation.  Think with callbacks (or, *lambdas*) and not return values.

Answer (score 0):

```
var lat;
var lon;
function getLocation(){
    ...same
}
```

Except! don't use "var" before the variable assignments for `lat` and `lon` within the function; that means they are from the global scope, and will be accessible whenever you need them.

All you need to do is get rid of is the "var" before `lon` within the function, and declare them first within the global scope.

Comment: Thanks, when I do the suggested above--the variables come back null ...any other suggestion?

Comment: The variables would come back `undefined` if they had not been set, `null` is a value and has to be set explicitly.

Comment: Shad, look at your answer again.  You just recommended global variables as a solution.  I suggest you go sit in the corner and think about what you've done ;)

Comment: @Peter haha, I admit global vars are not an elegant solution, but this isn't Java, global vars are perfectly valid.